# Populate textfield.text after segue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitextfield, segue

I have a show-type segue. I want destinationViewController `nameTextField` to contain some text in it when segue is performed. I tried doing:

```
override func prepare (for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "ToEditScreen" {
     
        let svc = segue.destination as! EditViewController
        svc.nameTextField.text = cars[selectedIndex!].name //crashes
        svc.nameString = cars[selectedIndex!].name
        }
    }
```

The error I get is: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value.
I know that `cars[selectedIndex!].name` is not nil.
If I delete the textfield line everything is fine and `nameString` does get its value which is equal to `cars[selectedIndex!].name`. I know I can do:

```
nameTextField.text = randomString
```

but it seems like an extra step. Can I populate textfield.text from original `ViewController`?

Comment: The view is not loaded at this point. You need to override `viewDidLoad` method in your `EditViewController` and populate textField. 
There is nasty way also, call `svc.loadViewIfNeeded()` right after `let svc = segue.destination....`

Comment: Why is it nasty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a string variable to the destination vc and set it there or

```
let svc = segue.destination as! EditViewController
svc.loadViewIfNeeded() // add this line
svc.nameTextField.text = cars[selectedIndex!].name
```